# Set visibility on/off on button in table

Tags: javascript, html-table, visibility

I am creating a table with a button in the 5th column. The button shall first be visible when the user clicks on the row of the table. I am having truble setting visibility on....

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = dataRaw.length; i > 0; i--) {

                var r = dataRaw[i-1];
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                row.id = r[0];
                for (var x = 0; x < r.length; x++) {

                    if (i === 1) {
                        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                        headerCell.innerHTML = r[x];
                        row.appendChild(headerCell);

                    } else {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(x);

                        if (x === 5) {

                            var btn = document.createElement('input');
                            btn.type = "button";
                            btn.className = "btn";
                            btn.id = r[0].toString();
                            btn.value = "Vis";
                            btn.style.backgroundColor = '#428bca';
                            btn.style.color = 'white';
                            btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            cell.appendChild(btn);

                        }
                        else {
                            cell.innerHTML = r[x];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

I have this listener on the table :

```
    $(function () {
        $('#errorTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            var requestID = this.id;

           document.getElementById(requestID).style.visibility = 'visible';
```

The button is "hidden" at start, but I cannot show it again.....Anyone ?

Comment: Please show your HTML snippet, and reduce the Javascript to only the parts that matter to resolve your issue

Comment: If I use style.display  = 'none', the whole row is hidden.....Only want to hid button in the row

Comment: Then you should simply use `$(this).find('button').first().hide();`

Comment: Looks like you are using the same ID value for the TR, and for the button element? IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each row has a single button, or you want to hide the first button inside the row\

```
$('#errorTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {

      //document.getElementById(requestID).style.visibility = 'visible';

       $(this).find('button').first().hide();           
       // or if you set your buttons as INPUTS:
       $(this).find('input[type=button]').first().hide();
}
```

notice: this method does not require the unique id of the row that was clicked. Unless you want to relay it back to the server.

## Edit

your code that generates the button also can use some modification:

```
if (x === 5) {
    var btn = $('<input>')
             .attr("type","button")
             .attr("id",r[0].toString())
             .attr("value","Vis")
             .css("background-color","#428bca")
             .css("color","white")
             .css("display","none")       // initially hidden
             .addClass("btn");

    btn.appendTo($(cell));
}
```

## Edit 2

To toggle visiblity of the button again, as you described in the comment, there is no need to invoke `.first()` here, since there is only one element with that ID.

```
$("#" +requestID+ "btn").show();
```

Comment: Works fine :) But, if I first want to hide then show, it does not work.... First I set:  btn.style.visibility = "hidden";    then I tried  $(this).find('button').first().show(); and $(this).find('input[type=button]').first().show(); .......but not working

Comment: @JoeDoe I edited my answer to accommodate your comment

Comment: your modification works, but messes other elements in site. Can't I use my version of the button, and use $(this).find to find button by id ? If I add btn.id = r[0].toString()+"btn" then each button has unique id different from tablerow id... ??

Comment: @JoeDoe I edited my answer again to show how you might show the button again